# TestRail integration with selenium using c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, testrail

I am new to TestRail tool and wanted to integrate all my UI Selenium automation test cases with TestRail. I have gone through the API Bindings of TestRail but they are only meant for API test cases. Can someone please please give me any idea to integrate TestRail with selenium using c#.

Comment: Would you be able to give more information on the problem? What are you trying to achieve? You can integrate any code that is running Selenium with Testrail as long as you call the correct API methods in your test framework.

What language or set up are you using?

Comment: @DeclanCarroll I've tried the below links codes but unfortunately didn't worked for  me http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api2/bindings-dotnet and https://www.gerbenvanadrichem.com/quality-assurance/basic-integration-of-automated-testcases-with-testrail/.

Comment: I've provided a link to an example in my answer. You would need to call the Testrail API to report the results of your tests.

Comment: Sorry for the delay response @DeclanCarroll I'll try and will update you.

Comment: Hey, did it work?

Answer (score 1):

What you would need to do to integrate it is to set up your test run as part of your set up code when you are running your Selenium tests.

There is a Nuget package that will allow you to integrate with Testrail if you are using the original test suite project style from Testrail.

https://github.com/zoosk/testrail-client

I've created an example project of a simple Selenium + NUnit + Testrail integration here:
https://github.com/shortstacked/SeleniumTestrailIntegration